# Authenticate ASP.NET Core OpenTelemetry /metrics endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, metrics, open-telemetry

`app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint();` adds an endpoint `/metrics` where `Prometheus` scrapes collected metrics.
The endpoint, however, does not have any autentication and can be called by everyone.

Is there a configuration for the endpoint to add some basic or custom autentication?

Answer (score 2):

`UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint()` lets you provide a predicate which returns true or false to serve the metrics endpoint or not. You can use the predicate to check authorization headers and then block or grant the request.

For example, you can check the `Basic` Authorization headers in the predicate as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication

```cs
app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint(
    context =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path != "/metrics") return false;
        var authHeader = context.Request.Headers.Authorization.FirstOrDefault();
        if (authHeader == null) return false;
        var authHeaderVal = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);
        if (authHeaderVal == null) return false;
        // RFC 2617 sec 1.2, "scheme" name is case-insensitive
        if (!authHeaderVal.Scheme.Equals("basic",
                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
             authHeaderVal.Parameter == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        var credentials = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeaderVal.Parameter));
        int separator = credentials.IndexOf(':');
        string name = credentials.Substring(0, separator);
        string password = credentials.Substring(separator + 1);
        return name == "your_username" && password == "your_password";
    });
```

Of course then your prometheus config must also match the basic auth credentials:

```yaml
    basic_auth: 
      username: your_username
      password: your_password
```

Answer (score 2):

Having Authentication enabled for metrics endpoint is one way , Have you considered another commonly used approach ->

**Creating a separate web server endpoint**, such as a new instance of KestrelMetricServer, on a different port. **Access to this endpoint is restricted by firewall rules**, allowing only specific IP addresses to connect. For a practical example, you can refer to the [sample](https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net/blob/master/Sample.Web.DifferentPort/Program.cs)  available on GitHub.

In this approach, the Prometheus metrics are exposed via a separate HTTP server, running alongside the main application. By configuring the firewall to only allow access from specific IP addresses, you can ensure that the metrics are accessible only to authorized parties. This provides an additional layer of security for your metrics endpoint.

Comment: We have decided to restrict the external access on an nginx.